# Need help with Zend Framework dynamic Namespaces

Tags: zend-framework, url, dynamic, namespaces

I want to make my system redirect unknown requests such as 
www.address.com/a_company
to the adress
www.address.com/companies/company/ and display the company a_company if it exists in the database, otherwise throw the user to a 404 not found page.

So in detail, I want to make namespace that is as the first example dynamically, if the company exist in the database, I have no problem connecting to the database and retrieving information or finding a way to parse a company name, I just need help how to make my system check and run a function every time the address doesn't exist and show the second page (/companies/company/)..

I am using an Acl as well, but I think it should be fine if the page is /companies/company and then possibly add /?c=a_company or similar.

Thank you.
/Marcus

Answer (score 0):

simply create a front controller plugin which checks the request params agains the database before the request is dispatched.